How to manage ClickHouse with Liquibase?
I use liquibase to manage migrations for a Postgres DB I have, and would like to do the same for a ClickHouse server I'm setting up.
I downloaded the JAR file for the JDBC connection from here, set driver=com.clickhouse.jdbc.ClickHouseDriver in the liquibase.properties file, and tried to run liquibase status.
I'm getting the following error, which looks like liquibase is having trouble creating the DATABASECHANGELOG table, due to no specifying the engine (that last part is my assumption).
Does anyone have recent experience managing ClickHouse migrations with liquibase? Were you able to find a work-around for this?
Unexpected error running Liquibase: Code: 42. DB::Exception: ORDER BY or PRIMARY KEY clause is missing. Consider using extended storage definition syntax with ORDER BY or PRIMARY KEY clause. With deprecated old syntax (highly not recommen
ded) storage MergeTree requires 3 to 4 parameters: 
name of column with date,
[sampling element of primary key],
primary key expression,
index granularity

Syntax for the MergeTree table engine:

CREATE TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] [db.]table_name [ON CLUSTER cluster]
(
    name1 [type1] [DEFAULT|MATERIALIZED|ALIAS expr1] [TTL expr1],
    name2 [type2] [DEFAULT|MATERIALIZED|ALIAS expr2] [TTL expr2],
    ...
    INDEX index_name1 expr1 TYPE type1(...) [GRANULARITY value1],
    INDEX index_name2 expr2 TYPE type2(...) [GRANULARITY value2]
) ENGINE = MergeTree()
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.LiquibaseCommandLine.lambda$execute$2(LiquibaseCommandLine.java:404)
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:200)
) ENGINE = MergeTree()
ORDER BY expr
[PARTITION BY expr]
[PRIMARY KEY expr]
[SAMPLE BY expr]
[TTL expr [DELETE|TO DISK 'xxx'|TO VOLUME 'xxx'], ...]
[SETTINGS name=value, ...]
[COMMENT 'comment']

See details in documentation: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/mergetree/. Other engines of the family support different syntax, see details in the corresponding documentation topics.

If you use the Replicated version of engines, see https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/replication/.
. (NUMBER_OF_ARGUMENTS_DOESNT_MATCH) (version 24.10.1.1301 (official build))
 [Failed SQL: (42) CREATE TABLE DATABASECHANGELOG (ID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, AUTHOR VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, FILENAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, DATEEXECUTED datetime NOT NULL, ORDEREXECUTED INT NOT NULL, EXECTYPE VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, MD5SUM V
ARCHAR(35), DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(255), COMMENTS VARCHAR(255), TAG VARCHAR(255), LIQUIBASE VARCHAR(20), CONTEXTS VARCHAR(255), LABELS VARCHAR(255), DEPLOYMENT_ID VARCHAR(10))]



 ORDER BY or PRIMARY KEY clause is missing
everything what you need show in error message
your table definition shall contains engine=MergeTree ORDER BY ...
